# How frequent is user feedback on an onsite poll?

Tags: user-engagement, research, surveys

I have a feedback poll on my website, and need to find some sourced data or article which states how frequently users generally give feedback when using online polls that look like this:

[image]

For example the wikipedia feedback poll is discussed [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Article_feedback), but I could not find data which shows what percentage of users actually used it to give feedback (e.g. "on average x% of visitors to articles gave feedback via the online poll").

Stack overflow also has a generic feedback poll for users who do not have an account / are not logged in. Any statistics for how frequently this poll is used would also be a good answer. I remember Jeff Attwood wrote a blog post once briefly mentioning that it was hardly ever used, but no numbers were mentioned.

Comment: The simpler your form, and the cleaner it looks, the more people will actually take the moment to rate your content. Perhaps a 1-5 stars bar similar to your background color (hovering over 4 starts will highlight the first 4) and clicking will submit the rating. Use cookies to "never show the form" to people who already rated. Don't say "Hey, before you leave, rate this!" The one you have pictured is not bad at all, but perhaps limit it to just one category "helpfulness" and make clicking the stars submit, rather than the extra step of the submit button. Remove the checkbox too.

Comment: @Adjam - I would recommend that you bring this answer to [meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) if you want to inquire directly w/the StackExchange admins.

Comment: @danlefree have done so [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142671/what-are-participation-rates-for-stack-overflows-was-this-post-useful-to-you-b) thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard and fast data which can produce a percentage of site visitors who will fill our a feedback rating. As was mentioned above a simple and easy to use form which only takes a second or two (such as a star rating system) is more likely to attract ratings than a more complicated form that requires multiple drop downs to be filled in and a button to be pressed. Additionally it also depends on the demographics you are targeting. I performed an experiment on one of my sites a few years ago inviting feedback into who likes feedback forms, the point being just to gather demographics on which users would submit feedback and which wouldn't and from what I found was that with the exception of a few outliers the vast majority of ratings where submitted by users over the age of 35, the way it worked out was...

- Approx 22% of total authenticated users filled out the feedback form
- Of the feedback received nearly 85% was from users over the age of 35
- Of the feedback received nearly 90% was of a positive nature in spite of deliberate changes made to the site for some users to simulate slow speed and user interface issues (including a few dozen users subjected to a huge number of lightboxes one after the other)

While the experiment was too small to come up with any firm conclusions I did come up with my own conclusion that users are more likely to fill out a feedback form if they are middle aged as the younger generations don't seem as interested in providing feedback (counter intuitive?), that users will tend to want to fill out feedback forms if they are simple and easy to fill out, and that users are less likely to take the time to fill out a feedback form if they don't have anything positive to say as they will see it possibly as  waste of time.

I should also add as a side note that the users involved in this experiment where already a part of the website community and had been informed previously that this experiment was going to be run and had the option of opting out of the experiment before it occurred and only 35% of the users opted out which made the results of the number of feedbacks received interesting given all the users who had participated in the experiment had chosen not to opt out.